# Solving Matrix Equations For Multivariate Interpolation in Python

Tags: python, matrix, interpolation

I am currently trying to conquer a hefty task that involves interpolating points (essentially extrema and x-intercepts) from an equation. There are multiple issues with doing this in Python, and in general. If I am correct, the number of coordinates must be a perfect square (for `V = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(xcoo,ycoo,[s,s])`, where s is the degrees of the (indirectly) outputted equation and V is the Vandermonde Matrix. But even when the above qualification is met, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "", line 1, in
>    multivariate([1,0,-1],[3,2,0],0,0,0) File
>   "/Users/user/Desktop/Proj/Interpolation.py", line 512, in multivariate
>           c = np.linalg.solve(V,zcoo)
>         File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py",
>   line 384, in solve
>           r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
>       TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting
>       was found for ufunc solve1

I don't really know what this means.
Even if I do get the values for c, I will need to multiply them by the equation of the Vandermonde matrix in symbolic form and somehow extract the equation out of the array, as I need to manipulate the expression afterwards.

Here is my code:

```
def multivariate(coef,exp,z,coords,t):
    if t == 0:
        y = Symbol('y')
        a = function(coef, exp) #Equation of function using the coef and exp (i.e. function([5,4,3],[3,2,0]) outputs 5*x**3 + 4*x**2 + 3
        b = function(coef, exp)
        b = b.subs(x, y)
        print(b)
        func = a + b
        r = f(coef, exp, 0) #Used to find y-intercept
        z = func - r
        print("z =",z)
        root = []
        crit3d = []
        crit2d = rootsofd(coef, exp)
        n = 0
        g = []
        k = []
        while n < len(crit2d):
            h = [crit2d[n]]
            h.append(crit2d[n])
            q = z.subs(x,h[0])
            q = q.subs(y,h[1])
            crit3d.append(q)
            h.append(q)
            g.append(h)
            k.extend(g)
            n = n + 1
        print(k) #coords of critical values 
        roots2d = [roots(fvalue(coef,exp))]
        roots3d = []
        o = []
        roots3d.extend(roots2d)
        o.extend([0])
        o = [o]
        roots3d.extend(o)
        print(roots3d)
        roots3d2 = roots3d
        roots3d = list(itertools.product(*roots3d))
        rev3d = list(itertools.product(*reversed(roots3d2)))
        roots3d.extend(rev3d)
        print(roots3d)
        n = 0
        w = []
        g = []
        while n < len(roots3d):
            m = list(roots3d[n])
            q = z.subs(x,m[0])
            q = q.subs(y,m[1])
            root.append(q)
            m.append(q)
            g.append(m)
            w.extend(g)
            n = n + 1
        print(root)
        print(w) #coords of roots
        coords = w
        coords.extend(k)
        print(coords) #Full x,y,z coordinates
        xcoo = [el[0] for el in coords]
        ycoo = [el[1] for el in coords]
        zcoo = [el[2] for el in coords]
        print("xcoo =", xcoo)
        print("ycoo=", ycoo)
        print("zcoo=", zcoo)
        s = len(xcoo)
        s = (s)**.5
        if s - (s-1) >= .5:
            s = round(s) - 1
        else:
            s = round(s)
        V = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(xcoo, ycoo, [s,s])
        c = np.linalg.solve(V,zcoo) #This is essentially where the error occurs
        poly(s+1,c)
        p = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyvander2d(x,y,[s,s])
        p = p*c #This will also become an issue
        r = 0
        o = []
        while s**2 > r:
            o.append(p.item(r))
            r = r + 1
        p = Poly(o)
```

I apologize for the long code; I need to show all of it in order to fully comprehend the scenario. Also, I don't really know where the error is coming from, better safe than sorry.

Any suggestions would really help me, as I am in a situation of exigency.

EDIT:

When I do `multivariate([5,4,-.2], [3,2,0], 0, 0 ,0)` I get the following long matrix:

```
[[ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2763932
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.0763932   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.02111456 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.00583592  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2763932
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.0763932   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.02111456 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.00583592  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.2         0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.04        0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.008       0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0016
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2763932
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.0763932   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.02111456 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.00583592  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.2         0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.04        0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.008       0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0016
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.7236068   0.5236068  -0.37888544  0.27416408  0.         -0.
   0.         -0.          0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.
   0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.          0.          0.
  -0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2763932
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.0763932   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.02111456 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.00583592  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.2         0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.04        0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.008       0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0016
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.7236068   0.5236068  -0.37888544  0.27416408  0.         -0.
   0.         -0.          0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.
   0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.          0.          0.
  -0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.2763932   0.0763932  -0.02111456  0.00583592  0.         -0.
   0.         -0.          0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.
   0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.          0.          0.
  -0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.7236068
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.5236068   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.37888544 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.27416408  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.         -0.2763932
  -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.          0.0763932   0.          0.
   0.          0.         -0.02111456 -0.         -0.         -0.         -0.
   0.00583592  0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.2         0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.04        0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.008       0.          0.          0.          0.          0.0016
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.7236068   0.5236068  -0.37888544  0.27416408  0.         -0.
   0.         -0.          0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.
   0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.          0.          0.
  -0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.2763932   0.0763932  -0.02111456  0.00583592  0.         -0.
   0.         -0.          0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.
   0.          0.         -0.          0.         -0.          0.          0.
  -0.          0.         -0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.          0.2         0.04        0.008       0.0016      0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [ 1.         -0.53333333  0.28444444 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.53333333
   0.28444444 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.28444444 -0.1517037
   0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.02301401 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.04315128
   0.02301401 -0.01227414  0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.02301401 -0.01227414
   0.00654621]
 [ 1.         -0.53333333  0.28444444 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.53333333
   0.28444444 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.28444444 -0.1517037
   0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.02301401 -0.1517037   0.08090864 -0.04315128
   0.02301401 -0.01227414  0.08090864 -0.04315128  0.02301401 -0.01227414
   0.00654621]
 [ 1.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.          0.
   0.          0.          0.          0.        ]]
```

When I do `multivariate([1,0,-1],[3,2,0],0,0,0)`, which has n coordinates in the end where n is a perfect square I get the following matrix (this is where the above error originates from):

```
[[ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 1.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: The error message is weird, but can you check whether some alphas are identical? Then the matrix would be singular and solve would fail.

Comment: @MartinKrämer how does one do this? And what do I do if they are identical? Would you like me to edit my question and provide the output of the matrix? I used the following equation in the error message because its matrix array is square at the last two dimensions.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to check the rank with numpy.linalg.matrix_rank. If it is not full rank, then the matrix is singular and you would want to look into confluent Vandermonde matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

Comment: Checking whether the determinant is 0 is probably even easier.

Comment: If either is not the case then your matrix is fine and it is some weird issue with numpy.lingalg.solve - no idea then.

Comment: You can also paste the matrix if you want sure, I can check it quickly.

Comment: @MartinKrämer when I do `np.linalg.det(V)` it does not give an output, even if I do `np.linalg.det(V) == 0`

Comment: I'd guess your numpy is somewhat broken. Any square matrix has a determinant and computation should be very fast. Even on pretty huge matrices I basically get instant answers. This fits the weird error message of your original problem. Perhaps check your installation?

Comment: @MartinKrämer I know for a fact that my installation is wonky. I have a Mac- enough said, am I right? I didn't want to run python in terminal, but I needed Anaconda for numpy, scipy, ... So I run/open up idle from the terminal so it has the modules. This could screw up some of the modules, like when I ran matplotlib some message came up about installation. However, I use numpy for other things in my code and they run fine.

Comment: Your matrices also look problematic. I can see duplicate rows in both of them.  So they generally have no or infinitely many solutions, i.e. under-determined system, and solve is not applicable as it requires full rank square matrices.

What you can do is find a numerical solution by minimizing the least squares error: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html 

But I cannot tell you whether this makes sense for your intended application or whether the matrices should not be under-determined in the first place.

Comment: @MartinKrämer I get a weird output from that. Assuming that it is the smaller matrix: `(array([-1.,  1.,  1.,  0.]), array([], dtype=float64), 3, array([ 2.32436633,  1.14718388,  0.53036809,  0.        ]))` is my output for the [1,0-1],[3,2,0] one. How do I use this exactly? I am not used to this form and need to now multiply it by the respective polynomial equation xy+x+y+1 (since there are 4 coordinates). `c[0]*x*y + c[1]*x + c[2]*y + c[3]` would be my output. Additionally, the issue is also that it's not always that equation; it varies with the # of points are are all the exps descending.